# When mac Awakes From Sleep Apple logo flashes?

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra

After Updating to mac os High Sierra Whenever Macbook awakes from sleep it flashes a white screen with apple logo and progress bar and sometimes it shows freezed image of the app that i was working on .

reset Smc , nvram and installed new os nothing fixed this .
Device:- Macbook Pro mid 2012 
Os:- mac os High Sierra

Comment: This sounds like macOS Safe Sleep. Does the progress bar look like this? - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201635

Comment: no. It Has A white background with apple logo and progress bar under it